# A way for selecting multiple option in single one unit test angular

Tags: angular

```html
 <select id="product" (change)="onProductChanged($event)">
    <option>--- Please Select ---</option>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"> {{ product.displayName }} </option>
</select>

    <select [(ngModel)]="envFilter" class="form-control" name="envSelector" (ngModelChange)="onChangeFilter($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let env of envs" [ngValue]="env">{{env}}</option>
</select>
```

in my angular similar to above code and i have to select muliple dropdowns in one unit test

Comment: one unit test means are you trying to write unit test case. Or you just need select dropdown that allows multiple selection.

Comment: In single unit test, i need to select multiple options like in my ui there are multiple dropdowns in one page